# How to show first item that comes from data source on dropdown

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to show the first at in datasource on my dropdown.

I am using the next code:

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="filtersForm" class="filters-row">
 <div class="flex-column">
  <select label="Number." [options]="aNumberDropdown" formControlName="dropdownNumber"></select>
  </div>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
  public filtersForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      dropdownNumber: ['']
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
  <form [formGroup]="filtersForm" class="filters-row">
    <div class="flex-column">
      <select label="Number." formControlName="dropdownNumber">
        <option *ngFor="let aNumber of aNumberDropdown" [ngValue]="aNumber">{{aNumber}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**component.ts**

```
  public filtersForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    dropdownNumber: [this.aNumberDropdown[0]]
  });
```

Comment: didnot work, i see on the screen too many [object Object][object Object]..

Comment: @dnyesil can you specify on the array aNumberDropdown type?

Comment: Yes. it's an array of SelectOption. What are its properties? What property is for the label?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `patchValue` function or set the value as default as shown in the first answer:

```
this.filterForm.patchValue({
   dropdownNumber: this.aNumberDropdown[0]
})
```

Comment: where should i add this?

Comment: After defining your form group - filtersForm.